# c# Strategy Pattern per user

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, code-structure

I have a very simple scenario.
My site's user can be either a monthly membership or an annual membership

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
}

public enum MembershipType
{
    MONTHLY,
    ANNUALLY
}
```

and then depending on the membership, I apply a different billing strategy:

```
public interface IBillingStrategy
{
    void Bill(User user);
}

if (user.MembershipType == MembershipType.ANNUALLY)
{
     _billingStrategy = new AnnualBillingStrategy();
}
else if (user.MembershipType == MembershipType.MONTHLY)
{
      _billingStrategy = new MonthlyBillingStrategy();
}
```

This is very straight forward and simple. Now business comes along and says "I want to look after my friend Bob, I want you to calculate his bill slightly differently to everyone else!"

So If I continue the pattern I can make a BobBillingStrategy. then I can add some extra logic, now I have 2 ways I can identify Bob

```
if (user.UserName.Equals("bob"))
{
     _billingStrategy = new BobBillingStrategy();
}
```

This feels dirty as I am hard coding a username, and just my luck bob creates a new user. So I can add a boolean property to my user called IsBob

```
if (user.IsBob)
{
     _billingStrategy = new BobBillingStrategy();
}
```

Both just seem to smell funny to me. And I can see what is going to happen, eventually I am going to start testing for Fred, and Ted also. My code above will work, but I am certain there must be a cleaner solution.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, like people answered here, you have only to implement those "friend-strategies" in code, but exact users that strategies must be used to should be configurable on database level. At least, that seems to be the least dirty solution for me.

Comment: Would not recommend using enum for storing type of membership at all. Make Membership a dynamic thing (see my answer)

Comment: Btw, is it possible to look at the problem from another angle? For example, not adding a new `IBillingStrategy` for Bob, but addind new business objects like, say, `Discount` that would be reusable for other users? That's just a thought though, i don't know your exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have Membership as a class that held default billing, etc. it would be a ton cleaner that a bunch of if's:

```
public class Membership
{

    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public BillingStrategy DefaultBillingStrategy {get; private set; }
    //Other properties

        public Membership(string name, BillingStrategy defaultBillingStrategy)
        {

            Name = name;
            DefaultBillingStrategy = defaultBillingStrategy;

        }

}
```

then, you do something like this with your User:

```
public class User
{

    //same as before

    public BillingStrategy BillingStrategy {get; set; }

    public User(string Name, Membership membership, BillingStrategy billingStrategy = null)
    {

        name = Name;
        MemberShip = memberShip;
        BillingStrategy = billingStrategy ? membership.DefaultBillingStrategy;

    }

}
enter code here
```

also; since a user does not want to pay for jan thorugh jun if they join in jul, you probably want to save some information about when membership expires on the user, and let the membership set this value on/after billing

Comment: just a typo: `User` is no longer `//same as before` since since you have to hold the `BillingStrategy`. And it seems to me that you unnecessarily complicate things on the side of `Membership`/

Comment: by "//Same as before" I meant the properties it otherwise had (name and membership).

I don't see how you can say I unnecessarily complicate Membership. I would rather say that hard-coding different types of membership as an enum, and then using a bunch of hard-coded if's to check that enum to change something as trivial as the duration of membership is to complicate things way more.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice the `BillingStrategy` property, my bad completely. You inject `BillingStrategy` into `Membership`, that means that some other class must control that process, or you even need a new one for that purpose. `BillingStrategy` now get injected into two classes and more mechanisms are needed to support it. I thing it is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: No problem. SOrry if I seem cranky. Too much coffee + little sleep + hungry = cranky coder :P

Comment: I edited my comment above. And yes, hard-coding lots of ifs is definitely worse than making `Membership` a class, that much i agree with you.

Comment: Yeah, there should definitively be some better mechanism for this, but this was written posthaste, as I am @ work :P

Answer (score 1):

make another variation of the billing procedure:

```
public enum MembershipType
{
    MONTHLY,
    ANNUALLY,
    SPECIAL1
}
```

That way you can at least assign the same procedure to some other "Friends"

Comment: My issue with this solution is that many years down the line, a future coder will have a lot more WTF/minute moments as it isn't very clear what "special1" is.Also it still losses the fact that that the user is Monthly or Annual (which may affect code logic elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

add some sort of coupon code mechanism, so that if you needs to calculate differently for other users then its flexible enough to do same.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does your IBillingStrategy do?

Is it responsible for actually billing the user as well as calculating what they should be billed?

If so I'd separate those responsibilities, introducing the concept of an `Invoice` and then allow user specific `Discount` to be applied to the generated `Invoice` before the `User` is actually billed.

I would probably combine the concepts of `Membership` and `BillingStrategy` (so `Membership` generate `Invoices`), use a `BillingAction` to encapsulate HOW the user is billed (Credit Card, Mailed Invoice, Briefcase of Unmarked Bills) introduce the concept of `Discounts` (each `User` can have many `Discounts`) to deal with the new requirement and wrap the whole thing up in a `BillingService`.

When hydrating a user from whatever store you have, I would give them an appropriate `Membership` (which in turn would be initialised with a set of `Discounts` and other information, like membership dates and whatnot) and an appropriate `BillingAction`.

Then as part of your billing process (maybe a nightly thing) you get the `Users`, push them through the `BillingService`, and underneath it generates `Invoices` and actions them using the `Users` `BillingAction`.